# How to autosum value on dropdown and radio select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sum

I'm working on an auto calculation form which is a total column will change after a radio and a dropdown is clicked. I can make the total change for both dropdowns but the problem occurs when I tried to add a radio option. Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
Ages 10+:
<select id="Adult" name="Adult">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
<br />Ages 3-9:
<select id="Child" name="Child">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
<br />Food
<input type="radio" name="food" id="food0" value="0" />
<label for="food0">No</label>
<input type="radio" name="food" id="food1" value="10" />
<label for="food1">Yes</label>
<table width="100%" border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>Product</td>
        <td>Ages 10+</td>
        <td>Ages 3-9</td>
        <td>Food</td>
        <td>Price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2 Day Ticket</td>
        <td>$235.00</td>
        <td>$223.00</td>
        <td><span id="food">0</span>

        </td>
        <td>$<span class="amount" id="2DayTotal"></span> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3 Day Ticket</td>
        <td>$301.00</td>
        <td>$285.00</td>
        <td><span id="food">0</span>

        </td>
        <td>$<span class="amount" id="3DayTotal"></span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4 Day Ticket</td>
        <td>$315.00</td>
        <td>$298.00</td>
        <td><span id="food">0</span>

        </td>
        <td>$<span class="amount" id="4DayTotal"></span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5 Day Ticket</td>
        <td>$328.00</td>
        <td>$309.00</td>
        <td><span id="food">0</span>

        </td>
        <td>$<span class="amount" id="5DayTotal"></span>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var numAdult = 0;
var numChild = 0;

$("#Adult").change(function () {
    numAdult = $("#Adult").val();
    calcTotals();
});
$("#Child").change(function () {
    numChild = $("#Child").val();
    calcTotals();
});
$('input[type=radio]').change(function(evt) {
    $('#food').html($(this).val());
});

function calcTotals() {
    $("#2DayTotal").text(235 * numAdult + 223 * numChild);
    $("#3DayTotal").text(301 * numAdult + 285 * numChild);
    $("#4DayTotal").text(315 * numAdult + 298 * numChild);
    $("#5DayTotal").text(328 * numAdult + 309 * numChild);
}
```

The issues are:

1. I'd like the food column change to it's value when a radio is click. It works only the first id.
2. After a radio is clicked. A fumction **calcTotals()** is called to sum an additional food cost.

Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/4Jegn/178/

Please be advice.

Comment: Have you tried the fiddle? It's the radio's value that showing in the food column and also sum with the total sum.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you're going after now.  I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I've made a demo of what I think you are wanting.  But first, I want to give you some tips.

The biggest problem with your original code is that you are assigning the ID `food` to 4 different `<span>` tags.  This is why you are experiencing the behavior where only the first cell is changing, and the other 3 are left alone.  Simply changing `food` to a `class` instead of an `id` made all 4 of them change as intended.

---

In your original code, you have:

```
numAdult = $("#Adult").val();
numChild = $("#Child").val();
```

You can sometimes run into problems using `.val()` with various input tags.  This is because `.val()` can return a string, number, or array - and can be unpredictable at times.  In your code, the value of `numAdult` was a `string`, while the value of `numChild` was a `number`.  To ensure that you get a `number`, you can do this:

```
numAdult = parseInt($("#Adult").val(), 10);
numChild = parseInt($("#Child").val(), 10);
```

`parseInt()` simply converts your `string` into a `number`.  A best practice for using `parseInt()` is to **always define the second argument**.  I won't confuse you with the details of it, so unless you are trying to parse binary, octal, or hexidecimal numbers (likely not), **just give the second argument a value of `10`**.

---

I also wanted to mention something jQuery-specific.  Here is another snippet of your code:

```
$("#Child").change(function () {
    numChild = $("#Child").val();
    calcTotals();
});
```

Notice that you have `$("#Child").val();` underneath `$('#Child').change(...)`.  Because you are using a jQuery event handler for `#Child`, it is better to change your second selector to `$(this).val()` .  You want to do this because DOM interactions are generally the slowest piece of any js code.  By using `this` instead of `$('#Child')`, you only query the document once instead of twice.

---

In your html, I noticed that you included `<span>`'s inside of your `<td>`'s so you could have a dollar-sign.  That is definitely one way to do it, but I did want to mention the [CSS `::before` psuedo element](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp).  In my demo, instead of manually typing in a dollar sign, I completely got rid of the `<span>` tags and used CSS to insert a dollar sign before the normal content.  Internet Explorer 8 and up supports it, so take that into consideration.

---

*Thanks for reading :) .  Alright, here is the [demo of what I think you want](http://jsfiddle.net/mvmudneg/).  Good luck.*

---

> how can I format the total with comma like 1,500 instead of 1500?

There are 2 ways to do it.  One way is to use regular expression, and the other is to loop through the string.  I think the regular expression path may be the most efficient, but I'm less familiar with RegExp than loops.  So this is what I came up with:

```
function commas(str) {
    var output = [],
        decimalIndex = str.indexOf('.'),
        count = 0;
    for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (count % 3 === 0 && count !== 0) {
            output.push(',');
        }

        if (decimalIndex === -1 || i < decimalIndex) {
            count++;
        }

        output.push(str[i]);
    }

    return output.reverse().join('');
}
```

I'm not updating it again, though.  I want to help push you in the right direction, not necessarily write your code for you every time you have a new requirement.

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mvmudneg/6/).

Comment: Eclecticist, one more question please? how can I format the total with comma like 1,500 instead of 1500???

Comment: @Wilf I updated my answer to include comma formatting.